# CAPTCHA Google em Java

Tags: jsp, captcha, requisição

Estou com problema em implantar o CAPTCHA do Google.

Na página do formulario adicionei o `script` e a `div` do captcha:

```
<head>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>

<form action='../envio_formularios/sendEmail_faca_proposta.jsp' >
<input name='Nome_0' id='nome_0' type='text'>
<input name='Email_1' id='email_1' type='text'>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="coloquei minha key aqui"></div>
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Até ai tudo bem....

Problema é no `sendEmail`, como faço pra validar a chave que foi retornada pelo script ?

Ai eu vi que tinha esse código em PHP:

```
 $secretKey = "Put your secret key here";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
      echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    } else {
      echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
    }
```

Como poderia converter essa requisição em JSP ?